# SQL server average when first value 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, average

How to get average with this query? Query works fine but I can't get average of all columns

```
 INSERT INTO db_name(
    AVERAGE_WEIGHT,
    RUNNING_TOTAL,
    ROLLING_AVERAGE)
    VALUES
    (onvert(real, '515,
    (convert(real, '515 + (SELECT SUM(average_weight)  FROM db_name)),
    (SELECT AVG(average_weight)  FROM db_name))

AVERAGE_WEIGHT    RUNNING_TOTAL     ROLLING_AVERAGE
515            NULL                  NULL
510            1025                  515
500            1525                  512.2
```

My last Column should be NULL, 512.2, 508.33 How to get right values? It is possible?

Comment: `(onvert` should be `(convert`, right?

Comment: @scragar yes wrong copy paste. But average still wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the rolling average and are using SQL Server 2012 or greater, just do:

```
select weight,
       sum(weight) over (order by id) as running total,
       avg(weight) over (order by id) as rolling average
from db_name;
```

This assumes that there is an `id` column that specifies the ordering of the rows.  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so a column is needed.

Note that your definition of rolling average is not the traditional definition.  The values would be 515, 512.5, and 508.3.  The above returns these.

If you want to insert these values into a table, then put an `insert` statement in front.  Your query is inserting and reading from the same table.  That seems strange.  You cannot get cumulative values this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO db_name(
    AVERAGE_WEIGHT,
    RUNNING_TOTAL,
    ROLLING_AVERAGE)
    VALUES
    (convert(real, '515'),
    (convert(real, '515') + (SELECT SUM(COALESCE(average_weight,0))  FROM db_name)),
    (SELECT AVG(COALESCE(average_weight,0))  FROM db_name))
```